# VLFeat SVM storage

Tags: serialization, computer-vision, svm, vlfeat

I am working with VLFeat and I have code that trains a linear SVM on my dataset. I would like to save the SVM to a file somehow so that I can load it up later and test it on several other datasets. What is the best way to do this?

edit: I am using the C++ API. Is it enough to save the model by using `vl_svm_get_model`? Would a simple serialization of the bytes of the svm struct work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not using this approach however it should be sufficient to save the model and bias terms to a file for later testing

Comment: Dont forget the bias multiplier!